# How to show all post related taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, widgets, taxonomy

I created several custom taxonomies for default WP post type. 
Does anyone knows any widget solution or have any idea for this: How to show (in sidebar) all post related taxonomies?

Example: If we go to single post page, on sidebar will will find all related taxonomies. When I created this post i put him in 4 different taxonomies, i.e. red, blue, orange and black.

Now on right side of post we have all post related taxonomies.

I hope I was understandable for you guys,
Thanx

Comment: This is a rather broad question: you have to register your custom widget to WP, code the widget itself, query with taxonomies etc. If you don't want to code it and need a plugin, look [here](https://et.wordpress.org/plugins/). *It has search filters,* so no worries with that.

Comment: I have done a broilerplate/template for a custom widget and also have done quite a few posts on related posts. Use the site search and look under my answers. All you need to do is, take the two and combine them ;-)